# android answer telephone

Tags: android

we can not use the java reflect to answer calls after android2.3.So another way found to acswer:

```
private void answerPhoneHeadsethook(Context context)
{
    // Simulate a press of the headset button to pick up the call
    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

    // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

I find a little information of `mediaButtonBroadcastReceive` in `AudiaService`, but I not find the direct class which dealing with the event.Who can tell me ?